# The place of "isolated" nominal and prepositional elements/groups within a transitivity analysis

Tags: prepositions, analysis, nominals, systemic-functional, transitivity

What is the place of "isolated" (i.e. "standing alone") nominal and prepositional elements/groups within a transitivity analysis (i.e. there is no mention of an explicit process), and how can one analytically incorporate them into the overall analysis in a meaningful way?

Comment: If you gave us an example of what you're talking about, instead of just using more terminology to describe your terminology, we might have some better idea how to answer your question. Or understand it.

Comment: I apologize if my question was unclear. In a case of applied linguistics, a letter text or a speech might act as a good example. E.g. the opening and closing in a formal letter or speech: "Dear x"/"Ladies and gentlemen", "Best regards"/"Your loving father" etc.

Comment: The salutation and the complimentary close are almost always fixed phrases, immune from most syntactic rules. They occasionally are full sentences, but frequently are just abbreviations of such formulas. From _I remain, sir, your most humble and truly obedient servant,_ to _Your most obedient servant, Your servant, Your most obedient, _Yours truly,_ and _Yours_ is not too hard to see. What place there is for these in a "transitivity analysis" (even with the i.e, it's not clear what that means) remains, however, unclear at best.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. By "transitivity analysis" I am referring to the analytical model formulated by M.A.K. Halliday where processes are realized by verbs. However, as Halliday does discuss prepositional phrases as some kind of "minor-processes" or "mini-verbs", only that it seems to be in the case of an actual verbal clause in which they arguably can introduce a nominal element as an "indirect" participant in the main process, I wondered what would happen to the analysis of nominal and prepositional elements in instances of no explicit mentioning of any so called process.

Comment: Things get deleted all the time when they're predictable. _Ever go to Europe?_ is missing an auxiliary verb and a subject pronoun, but they're recoverable. And then there's _Bill ordered steak, and Mary fish_, where the second clause doesn't have a verb at all -- though it, too, is recoverable. Halliday's theory isn't much used any more.